# Wait for uninstaller to finish using batch

Tags: batch-file, wait, nsis, uninstallation, taskmanager

I would like to uninstall a few programs using batch and wait for each program to finish uninstalling before doing the other. The problem is that some of these uninstallers don't call other programs and aren't in the task manager, so START /WAIT wouldn't work. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: If those programs were installed internally through an .msi package then maybe it'll be possible to use `start /wait MsiExec.exe /X{5481F163-B9E5-30A8-8441-4DBBB87D6AA2}` for example. The exact product code can be found using `reg query`.

Comment: they aren't. They are custom uninstallers, where the the uninstaller isn't even in the task manager during the uninstall. I'm not sure what programs it is calling.

Comment: 1. The uninstall string should be present in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`. 2. The process should be visible on the `processes` tab in the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows and that the programs were installed with .msi packages,

Uninstalling a program in a batch file is as easy as using MSIEXEC. Full documentation on using MSIEXEC can be found on [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc759262(v=WS.10).aspx)

To find the GUID of the installation that you would like to Uninstall, just use wmic in Command prompt:

```
wmic product get > C:\InstalledProgramsList.txt
```

Then navigate to C:\InstalledProgramsList.txt and use ctrl + F to find the desired product and associated GUID

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. 2 things: I don't see in the link provided where I can wait until the install is done before continuing. Also, my programs are 64 bit using an installer that doesn't register with the WMIC.

Comment: @Wajo357 If you create a batch script for Windows with msiexec, each command will be run sequentially when the previous command has finished. Additionally, `wmic product get` should work for all x64 & x86 applications that are installed as `.msi packages`

Comment: @Wajo357 Ah I see that you are working with a custom installer. Try searching through: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` OR `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I got it. This is the code I'm using, where I created a subroutine that waits for the task to finish.

```
:waitforuninstallation
timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %1" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%1">NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto waitforuninstallation
exit /b
```

This can be called using:

```
call :waitforuninstallation PROGRAMNAME.exe
```

Where PROGRAMNAME is the task running in the task manager. 
Edit: made the subroutine carry an argument

Answer (score 0):

There's a really annoying trend with free installers made by [NSIS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/):  Cisco Amp, Folding@Home, PsychoPy, Anaconda, PyCharm.  The uninstaller exe quits, and something called Un_A.exe takes over and does the rest.  In this case, you'd have to wait for that process to finish instead.

```
powershell while (! (get-process Un_a -ea 0)) { sleep 1 }; 'waiting'; wait-process Un_a
```

Or if you want the exit code of un_a:

```
powershell while (! ($proc = get-process Un_A -ea 0)) { sleep 1 }; $handle = $proc.handle; 'waiting'; wait-process Un_A; exit $proc.exitcode
```

Comment: _The NSIS uninstaller copies itself to the temporary directory, runs the temporary uninstaller created and then exits. This is done so it will be able to delete itself._ (c) [When I use ExecWait uninstaller.exe it doesn't wait for the uninstaller?](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/When_I_use_ExecWait_uninstaller.exe_it_doesn't_wait_for_the_uninstaller)

Comment: @AntonK This is a bad design from an administrator's point of view.  You don't normally know when the uninstall completes, and what the error code is.  Plus uninstalling one version, and upgrading to a newer version becomes tricky, since both the uninstaller and the installer can run at the same time.